# Jquery .delay().fadeOut cancel/clear queue.. Is it possible? How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I need some help here..
Is it possible to cancel the chaining delay?

```
Mn.Base.TopBox.show = function(timedur){
    $('#element').fadeIn().delay(timedur).fadeOut();
}


Mn.Base.TopBox.cancelFadeout = function(){

}
```

I read about queuing and tried some different approaches but I hadn't success...

```
    $('#element').stop();

    $('#element').queue('fx', []);
```

---

Thanks in advance,

Pedro

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It isn't, [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) doesn't play well with anything else since the timer keeps ticking and a [`.dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) is executed when it's up...regardless of if you cleared the queue and added a whole new one.

It's better to use `setTimeout()` directly if you intend to cancel, for example:

```
Mn.Base.TopBox.show = function(timedur){
  $('#element').fadeIn(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout(function() { elem.fadeOut(); }, timedur));
  });
}

Mn.Base.TopBox.cancelFadeout = function(){
  clearTimeout($('#element').stop().data('timer'));
}
```

What this does is set the timer and store it using [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), and when clering the animations, we're both calling [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop anything in process, *and* stopping that timer.

There's still the *potential* here for issues if you're firing this very rapidly, in which case you'd want to switch to storing an array of delays, and clear them all.